# Read data from non-json response

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I have this fetch request:

```
    fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbeautify/1.7.5/beautify.js')
     .then(function (result) {
       console.log('here is our content:', result.body);
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
       console.error(err.message);
     });
```

...

`result.body` is a `ReadableStream` last time I checked. The data coming back is not JSON, so `result.json()` throws an error.

How do I read the text from the response?

Comment: have you tried `result.text()` ?

Comment: idk you tell me I could not find an example of that anywhere

Comment: oh, sorry, the `?` wasn't because I don't know, let me edit the comment - it should've read *have you tried `result.text()` ?*

Comment: thanks I think your suggestion worked

Comment: if you want to access text response, then there's no thinking required :p

Comment: lol do you think I need any special headers?

Comment: if it works it works I guess

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes, so this is how it should be:

```
fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.7.5/beautify.js').then(function (result) {
  return result.text();
})
.then(function (result) {
  console.log('here is our content:', result);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
});
```